# Ctrl - Tab key binding doesn't work in Linux

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have set a key binding in Emacs using:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'switch-view )
```

: It works in Windows but Emacs in Linux seems to ignore it. Any ideas why?

My version of Emacs is 23.2 running in text mode (.nw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In text mode, Emacs depend upon the terminal or the console for keys combination. Terminals and consoles don't support as many keys combination as Xorg and windows do, and C-TAB is a combination that don't exist in text mode: TAB is already the same than C-i, and C-C-something don't exists.

Answer (score 2):

The window manager you are using is most likely 'kidnapping' it.

On mine (which is KDE), `C-tab` cycles through applications on the current desktop.  You can configure which keystrokes should be ignored though... but your best bet may be to map `switch-view` to another key sequence in your `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: I'm running GNOME and the keybinding of the original question works fine for me in GNU Emacs 23.1.1, so it's certainly not an Emacs problem on GNU/Linux in general.